# datatable sorting in typescript using angular4

Tags: angular, typescript

Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'sort' since it isn't a known property of 'datatable'.I am getting error like this.In detailsall got the data in descending only however when it comes to full gridview at time it is in ascending order.First fall it's not accepting the sort in html

In backend also i set descending order and it's working descending order.
The below code id html part

```
<datatable (click)="updateform()" [options]="{
                            data:detailsall,
                 columns: [
                 {data:'id'},
                 {data:'address'},
                 {data:'city'},
                 {data:'state'}
                 ],
                 buttons: [
                 'colvis'
                 ]
                 }" (sendRecord)="getArticleRecord($event)" tableClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" [sort]="sorting">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th data-class="expand">Id</th>
                      <th data-class="expand">Address</th>
                      <th data-class="expand">City</th>
                      <th data-class="expand">state</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                <datatable>
```

The below code is typescript:

```
sorting: any = {
        column: 'id',
        descending:true
      };
```

Comment: What `datatable` is that?

Comment: responsive datatable only, that template look like below                                    <table (click)="selectRecord()" class="dataTable responsive {{tableClass}}" width="{{width}}" sorting>
        <ng-content></ng-content>
      </table>

Answer (score 0):

I think you doesn't marked field `sort` as input

```
@Component({
...
})
class DatatableComponent {
  @Input() sort: { column: string, descending: boolean };
  ...
}
```

Comment: yeah it's true after that i added.

Comment: And after that the problem did not disappear?

Comment: export class DatatableComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() public options: any;
  @Input() public filter: any;
  @Input() public detailsFormat: any;
  @Input() public table: any;
  @Input() public sort:{ column: string, order:string };
  @Input() public paginationLength: boolean;
  @Input() public columnsHide: boolean;
}